# Operating a load cell below excitation voltage

Tags: signal-processing, instrumentation

I currently have [this](https://www.omega.com/pressure/pdf/LC703.pdf) load cell, which has a 10V excitation voltage. However, there is a very nice/convenient load cell amplifier that works with an excitation voltage of 5 VDC.

What are the consequences of operating a cell at a voltage lower than the normal excitation? Just increased noise in the signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load cell you linked to has a line item on the specs that says "Output: 2 mV/V nominal".  Let's just say that you picked the version with 100 lbf full scale output.  What that means is this: if you use a 1 V excitation, you'll get a response something like this

```
Load    Output
  0 lbf   0 mV
 50 lbf   1 mV
100 lbf   2 mV
```

Now if you use a 10 V excitation, you'll get this

```
Load    Output
  0 lbf   0 mV
 50 lbf  10 mV
100 lbf  20 mV
```

So if you want to use a 5V excitation, it will work perfectly fine.  Just do the math on the expected output.

Regarding your comment on noise. The signal to noise ratio will be likely be better with a higher excitation voltage.  So yes, if you use 5 V instead of 10V, you probably have a slightly worse signal to noise ratio. Depends on your application and the precision required as to whether that will be acceptable.

Comment: So given that, [this](https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=http-3A__www.interfaceforce.com_index.php-3FINF-2DUSB2-2DUniversal-2DSerial-2DBus-2DSingle-2DChannel-2DPC-2DInterface-2DModule-26mod-3Dproduct-26show-3D158&d=DwMFAg&c=ODFT-G5SujMiGrKuoJJjVg&r=-d6YV7HVeLzPO2awmjJaVDz5hgBKJh21xo9ENYAXsCs&m=eguOoNyxAykhxxqxv37oSvQpDq4qNypcpA1xS-DRDSA&s=uWeLlXAObFEW4z6XZxFy8OwL7wnnSsIN7FVpCYsZzdk&e=) product works fine for my purpose? I'm having trouble navigating the selection process for hooking up a load cell to a pc correctly, so a catch all system (while probably suboptimal) may meet my needs...

Comment: I have not used that particular product, but it looks like it should work.